# Searching for term inside text

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, search, split

```
$('#test').submit(function (event) {
var stocks = [
    ["STI,GOOG/NYSE_STI,SunTrust Banks"],
    ["AAPL,GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL,Apple Inc"]
];
var symbol = $("#textbox").val();
var count = 0
for (var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
    if (stocks[i][0][0] == symbol[0]) {
        for (var j = 0; j < symbol.length; j++) {
            if (stocks[i + j]) {
                count++

            }

        }
    }

    if (count == symbol.length) {

        var company = stocks[i][0]
        var companynocomma = company.split(",");
        var ticker = companynocomma[0];
        var exchange = companynocomma[1];
        var name = companynocomma[2];
        $('#GDP').append('<li>' + ticker + '</li>');
        $('#GDP').append('<li>' + exchange + '</li>');
        $('#GDP').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');

    }
}

event.preventDefault();
})
```

The goal for this code is to be able to type a ticker symbol such as "AAPL" into a textbox, the code will be able to find that "AAPL" in the stocks array, then split up the array into three separate arrays [AAPL],[GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL],[Apple Inc]. How can I make this code work?

http://jsfiddle.net/HthN2/11/

Comment: Do you want to verify if typed symbols are present in array?

Comment: yes, and then once verified splitting that array into three seperate arrays. @vladkras

Comment: This code should do what you asked for. `var stocks = [
    ["STI,GOOG/NYSE_STI,SunTrust Banks"],
    ["AAPL,GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL,Apple Inc"]
], 
symbol = 'AAPL',
wrapInArray = function (item) { return [item]; },
result;


stocks.some(function (arr) {
   if (arr[0].indexOf(symbol) !== -1) return result = arr[0].split(',').map(wrapInArray);
});

console.log(result);`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do by your code. `stocks[i][0]` and `symbol[0]` are also string, you want to campare with their first char by anthor [0]?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.


var stocks =     [
    ["STI,GOOG/NYSE_STI,SunTrust Banks"],
    ["AAPL,GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL,Apple Inc"]
];
var symbol = $("#textbox").val();
for (var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {

   if(stocks[i][0].match(symbol)) {
            var company = stocks[i][0];
            var companynocomma = company.split(",");
            var ticker = companynocomma[0];
            var exchange = companynocomma[1];
            var name = companynocomma[2];
            console.log(companynocomma);
            $('#GDP').append('<li>' + ticker + '</li>');
            $('#GDP').append('<li>' + exchange + '</li>');
             $('#GDP').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
     }

 }
```

Comment: Also, the best way would be to have your stocks[] arranged in a different way. This is too tedious. As @user3397771 said, you can create your stocks[]

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you have structured your stocks data so that you are forced to do that messy iteration and splitting. Since you know that you will need to retrieve a stock by its ticker symbol, why not create a stocks object with the symbols as keys? Furthermore, instead of using a single string to hold the various stock properties (ticker, exchange, and name), it seems to me these data would be much better suited to object properties. For example:

```
var stocks = {
   'aapl': {
       'ticker': 'AAPL',
       'exchange': 'GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL',
       'name': 'Apple Inc'
   },
   'sti': {
      'ticker': 'STI',
      'exchange': 'GOOG/NYSE_STI',
      'name': 'SunTrust Banks'
   }
};
```

This way, obtaining your stock and its properties becomes much more simplified:

```
var stock = stocks[$("#textbox").val().toLowerCase()];
if (stock) {
   $('#GDP').append('<li>' + stock.ticker + '</li>');
   $('#GDP').append('<li>' + stock.exchange + '</li>');
   $('#GDP').append('<li>' + stock.name + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: `if (stock)`? what r u checking?

Comment: I am getting the data from a json file that gives me the stock information like this, so I do not think I can use objects for this.
AAQ_AX,YAHOO/ASX_AAQ_AX,Aaq Holdings Ltd 
AIR,GOOG/NYSE_AIR,AAR Corp. 
ARZ,GOOG/FRA_ARZ,AAR CORP. DL 1 
AAALF,GOOG/PINK_AAALF,AAREAL BANK AG 
AAALY,GOOG/PINK_AAALY,Aareal Bank AG 
ARL,GOOG/FRA_ARL,Aareal Bank AG

Comment: @vladkras: if (stock !== undefined)

Comment: @user3380357: Could you not parse the json data and build the stocks object upon loading the json file?